# Excel formula needed - OR condition combined with IS NOT condition

Tags: excel

In my spreadsheet I am trying to determine if certain company properties have a website active or inactive. In excel the websites in the according column either show as 'http' or 'www'.

I have solved this with the following formula: `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("http",RC[-2])),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("www",RC[-2]))),"Active","Inactive")`

However, some colleagues have complicated with entries like 'removed_http' or 'removed www'. Is there a way that I combine the above with some kind of ISNOT logic? I.e. the cell should either show 'www' or 'http' but not cells containing 'removed' in order to show 'active'. Any ideas?

Comment: why not use if and left statements, change the cell refrence as required, example: =IF(LEFT(A1,3)="www","Active",IF(LEFT(A1,4)="http","Active","Inactive"))

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `LEFT` function with `OR` and `IF` like this:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(B5;4)="http";LEFT(B5;3)="www");"Active";"Inactive")
```

This comparing with `=` is case insensitive, if you need a case sensitive comparing, use `EXACT` function